# Insert variable as object in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I have a simple variable:

```
var spanId = 'hi';
```

Now, I want to generate this:

```
$('#hi')
```

using the variable.

So I tried:

```
$('#' + spanId)
```

But that didn't work. Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: It should work. Can you post some more code? How can you tell it isn't working?

Comment: What do you mean by "generate"?

Comment: @Kobi: I'll post more code. I know it's not working because (1) I'm getting a Firebug error (object undefined) and (2) it's not doing what it's supposed to be doing.

@BGerrissen: could you elaborate?

Comment: @pekka he means he wants a selector to select an id based on a variable in his case spanId I believe.

Comment: So, if you write `$('#hi')` everything's working well, but `$('#' + spanId)` fails?

Comment: Ahhhh damnit. I'm sorry for being misleading. @Kobi: You're right, it works. I defined the variable within a function, so when I was using it under another function, it wasn't 'defined'...Damnit!@$ I'm a fool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please note that the ["+"-sign is a css selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators), this might be a problem.

__________________        UPDATE           __________________

I quickly checked it (See http://jsfiddle.net/r7MgY/1496/), it seems to work.

Code:

html (in body):

```
<div id="hi">test</div>​
```

css:

```
#hi {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ffb;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #999;​
}
```

jquery:

```
$(function() {
    var spanId = "hi";
    alert($('#' + spanId).css('backgroundColor'));​
});
```

Comment: This is the wrong answer.
+ sign would never cause any problems because '#' + spanId would return a string that would then be passed to the $ function.

$(query) and $('#' + spanId) are equivalent.

There must be some other problem in the code

Comment: You are right: i posted that '+' is a css selector, and that it "might" be a problem. In the meantime i checked it, and updated my post stating that it isn't a problem